How would I add a picture as a background directly to a JPanel
Is there any way to add a background without using a new JPanel?
I am making a dungeon themed minesweeper game in Java using Swing and need to have a different image as a background. My game consists of one main JFrame and the title screen, and the three difficulties as JPanels.
Adding a new Panel to add a background picture would be really difficult as it would mess with a lot of my code. I basically just want to "stick" the background to the back of the JPanel while also having it at a back layer, without covering any of the buttons.

Override the paintComponent(...) method of your JPanel to draw the image. See Background Panel for  a simple example. Adding a new Panel to add a background picture - so you would replace the default content pane of your JFrame with the panel where you do the custom painting.

This it how I did it. Overriding the paintComponent
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import vokabeltrainer.common.ApplicationImages;

public class TrashCanBackgroundPanel extends JPanel
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -7918923007938243168L;

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (ApplicationImages.getTrashcanBackground() != null)
      {
         int x = this.getParent().getWidth() / 2 - 1000 / 2;
         int y = this.getParent().getHeight() / 2 - 620 / 2;
         g.drawImage(ApplicationImages.getTrashcanBackground(), x, y, this);
      }
   }
}

The width of the image is 1000 pixel and the height 620 pixel.
Just set the JPanels layered on top
setOpaque(false)


i have two solutions might help you :
import javax.imageio.ImageIO ;
import javax.swing.JPanel ;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage ;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon ;
import java.awt.Graphics ;
import java.awt.Graphics2D ;
import java.io.IOException ;

public class LoadImage extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage ;
    ImageIcon image ;
    public LoadImage()  {
        // If you want to load your image inside the resources, do this
        try {
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/your/location.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace() ;
        }

        // do this if you want to load your image outside the program
        image = new ImageIcon("path/to/your/location.png") ;
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // for bufferedImage 
        if (bufferedImage != null) {
            g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null) ;
        }
        // for image 
        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, null) ;
        }
    }
}

i have a library that can handle your loading files, saves, images, wav musics from various locations named JStreamLoader, you can check it if you want.
JStreamLoader library on GitHub
